# How to make things bigger on the screen without changing the resolution?

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, cinnamon, resolution

I'm using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit.

My monitor's native resolution is 1280x1024 (5:4), but I use it at 1024x768 (4:3) because I find everything too small at 1280x1024. The problem is that the image gets blurry at 1024x768.

I've tried to add a custom resolution (1025x820) with the native aspect ratio (5:4), but the image isn't as sharp as I'd like.

Is there a way to make everything on the screen bigger? Not just the Cinnamon UI or Firefox, but absolutely everything, as if I was at a lower resolution?

I'm a long time Windows XP user and I'm trying out Linux for the first time. However, the image is blurrier than in Windows. On Windows the image isn't good either (at a lower than native resolution), but it's not that bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you downscale the resolution, it's almost certainly going to be blurry. You are trying to fir fractions of virtual pixels into single hardware pixels, and it just doesn't work well. It'll be much crisper to use the native resolution, and scale the UI. Unfortunately, you'll have to scale each program (and the desktop environment and window manager) individually.

Comment: @Sparhawk What do you mean by "window manager"? Also, is it possible to scale the desktop environment by a factor of a number between 1 and 2? Using the GUI, I can only double the size of the UI.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), but the details aren't important I guess. It's just that you'd want to scale the titlebars, etc. as well. I'm not sure about the specifics of scaling in Cinnamon; I don't use it. Presumably there is some way to set font size, at least.